# How to set value for defineProperty by string name?

Tags: javascript

I want to create output interface with an HTML page with help define properties for it but don't find how I can set a variable by name for the properties.

```
var _root = {};
var value = 2;

Object.defineProperty(_root, "MyProperty", {
    get: function(){
        return value;       
    }       
    ,
    set: function(val){
         value = val;       
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
}); 

function SetValue( nameProperty ,  value  ){
  nameProperty = value; 
}   

function GetValue( nameProperty){
   return  eval(nameProperty);  
}   

SetValue("_root.MyProperty","35"); // This function is called from C#   webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("SetValue" , new Object[]{"_root.MyProperty","35" });     

console.log( GetValue( "_root.MyProperty"));
```

**Edit**
I tried to set value with eval but it doesn't work.

```
function SetValue( nameProperty ,  value  ){
    var ob = eval(nameProperty);
    ob =value;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working. What's the problem?

Comment: I need to set value but know only Property by string.  For example eval("_root.MyProperty") = 34 doesn't work

Comment: `defineProperty(_root, propname, {...})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution my issue.

```
function SetValue( nameProperty ,  value  ){
    nameProperty = nameProperty.replace( "_root.",'');
   _root[nameProperty] = value; 
}
SetValue("_root.MyProperty","35");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping things in quotes, which is passing in [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). You want to pass in the object property as your first attribute, and a number as your second. But you're basically passing in meaningless text.

Try this:

```
SetValue(_root.MyProperty, 35); 
console.log( GetValue( _root.MyProperty));
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand  you, but _root.MyProperty iit doesn't string.  For set any value  for property  I  have to use function( NamePropeptyByName,  setValue);

Comment: @askeet - I have no idea what you're talking about. No such function appears in your question, and in fact the code in your question works.

Comment: @askeet - I've updated my answer. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: SetValue use string as input parameter because it's call from output browser. The environment does not know anything about these properties, except for their string names. So  I've checked  SetValue(_root.MyProperty, 35);  doesn't set value 35 in Google Chrome.